# Python. Не могу получить ответ на запрос списка водителей fleet-api.taxi.yandex.net

Tags: json, requests, яндекс-такси

Нужна ваша помощь, не понимаю, в чем ошибся. Пишу в соответствии с документацией https://fleet.yandex.ru/docs/api/?lang=ru на языке Python, но все равно код не выводит список водителей в консоль.

```
import requests
import json
import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"


url = 'https://fleet-api.taxi.yandex.net/v1/parks/driver-profiles/list'

headers = {'X-API-Key': 'inXVNAEujErWUtpuQArgrosqOndTi', 'X-Client-ID': 'taxi/park/4078fd71a83ff2d84b6f4680c'} # не оригинал

data = {
  "fields": {
    "account": [
      "balance"
    ],
    "car": [
      "color"
    ],
    "current_status": [
      "status"
    ],
    "driver_profile": [
      "last_name"
    ],
    "park": [
      "name"
    ]
  },
  "limit": 200,
  "offset": 0,
  "query": {
    "park": {
      "account": {
        "last_transaction_date": {
          "from": "string",
          "to": "string"
        }
      },
      "driver_profile": {
        "id": [
          "211dfdb6gk054u8c8cc9" #не оригинал
        ],
        "work_rule_id": [
          "bc43tre6ba054db3ckfgvcb" #не оригинал
        ],
        "work_status": [
          "working"
        ]
      },
      "id": "ff8c228fd2d844073b6f4" #не оригинал
    },
    "text": "string"
  },
  "sort_order": [
    {
      "direction": "asc",
      "field": "driver_profile.created_date"
    }
  ]
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(headers))
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

Получаю следующую ошибку в косноль:

```
    400
{'message': 'query must be present'}
```

Помогите пожалуйста составить правильно код, чтоб все таки ответ пришел)

Answer (score 0):

Вы в data (где отправка POST-запроса идет) передаете заголовки headers, а нужно data ))

Вы хотите передать json данные? Если да, то в заголовках запроса нужно добавить так:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-API-Key': 'inXVNAEujErWUtpuQArgrosqOndTi', 'X-Client-ID': 'taxi/park/4078fd71a83ff2d84b6f4680c'}
```

и тут еще так:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Comment: если будете по ходу кода еще отправлять какие-то запросы где нужно указывать заголовки, то рекомендую сделать так: 

sess = requests.Session()
sess.headers.update(headers) , ну а потом обращаться response = sess.post ( ... )

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Поправил, но теперь почему то ответ такой: 400
{'message': 'query.park.account.last_transaction_date.from must be datetime in ISO 8601 format, like 2018-12-31T23:59:59+0300'}, а если в query-account-last_transaction_date from и to со string изменить на datetime, ошибка  :   raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type module is not JSON serializable

Comment: а это уже логическая ошибка от API яндекса. В ответе вам говорится, что дата должна быть в формате ISO 8601. Самый простой способ добиться этого - my_date = str(datetime.now())[0:19].replace(' ', 'T')+'+0500' (только часовой пояс поменяйте на свой, в моем случае это будет +0500)